# SQL: Auto insert the a value from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables the first one is "student":

```
    id (PK) "auto_inc"
    student_name
    email
```

The second one is "bill":

```
    id (PK) "auto_inc"
    student_id (FK -> id)
    total_balance
```

I am trying to auto-insert the last 'id' into 'student_id' when I add a new student in the same query.
This is my query to add a new student to the table

```
insert into student (name, major, emailAddress)
   values ( :name, :major, :emailAddress )
```

For example:

```
id= 1
student_name= "Mike"
email= "mike@mail.com"

bill table:
id= 1
student_id= 1 "from 'student' table"
total_balance= 100
```

I do not have much experience with SQL DB, I am recently using it.

Comment: Look for `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. After the first query, you can call this for the id needed to use in the second query.

Comment: You can't insert data into two tables with a single query. You can do it with two successive queries from your PHP code, or you can write a stored procedure to do it.

Comment: Or you can try to use `TRIGGER`  as documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html). Create trigger after insert on table `student`, and inside this trigger, you can write statement to insert to `bill` table

Comment: Use LAST_INSERT_ID() for MySQL. First insert into student table. Then insert into bill. There will be 2 insert queries. First for student and second for bill. Write both queries in stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I can advice next approach:

1. create table `student` with unique key `email`

```sql
create table student (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  student_name varchar(255),
  email varchar(255) unique key
);
```

2. use next PHP code:

```php
<?php

$name = "Barry Block";
$email = "barry.b@gmail.com";
$balance = 500;

$student_sql = "
    insert into student (student_name, email)
    values ( :name, :emailAddress )";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($student_sql);
$stmt->execute([':name'=>$name, ':emailAddress'=>$email]);

$bill_sql = "
    insert into bill (student_id, total_balance)
    select id, :balance from student where email = :emailAddress";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($bill_sql);
$stmt->execute([':balance'=>$balance, ':emailAddress'=>$email]);
```

[Test MySQL & PHP code online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=d08ad09e6c04cc619cb958d23e2c106b&sqlses=027b4bc1a773485db24bf22063eedf3c&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Since it’s two queries, why _wouldn’t_ you just use the last inserted Id from the first query? This answer  avoids the question, and you won’t always be able to do that.